# How do I listen for trx events on tron network? (Tronweb) nodejs

Tags: node.js, blockchain, cryptocurrency, tron, tronweb

I already know that with this method "tronweb.contract().at(contractAddress).Transfer.watch()" I can listen to transfer events of a specific contract, but what I don`t know is that how can I listen for TRX intself?

Answer (score 0):

There's no methods for that as mentioned in official docs you can use Kafka or Mongodb plugin and connect that to a node for this purpose, but there's also HTTP API,

[event query http](https://github.com/tronprotocol/documentation-en/blob/master/docs_without_index/plugin/event-query-http.md)

you can create an interval to fetch the result and when the desired output came in hand clear that

TRON network produces new block every ~3 secs